# DSE/Cassandra CQL now() does not work for timestamp type

Tags: cassandra, cql, datastax-enterprise

I am having troubles with using `now()` function with `timestamp` type.

Please take a look at the following code:

Table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE "Test" (
    video_id UUID,
    upload_timestamp TIMESTAMP,
    title VARCHAR,
    views INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (video_id, upload_timestamp)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (upload_timestamp DESC);
```

The problematic INSERT query:

```
INSERT INTO "Test" (video_id, upload_timestamp, title, views)
    VALUES (uuid(), now(), 'Test', 0);
```

The INSERT query seems looking fine to me. However, when I execute it, I see the following error:

`Unable to execute CQL script on 'XXX': cannot assign result of function now (type timeuuid) to upload_timestamp (type timestamp)`

What I am doing wrong here?

I use DataStax Enterprise 4.5.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

now() returns a timeuuid, not a timestamp. You clould try dateOf(now()). Have a read of this from the docs:

> dateOf and unixTimestampOf
>
> The dateOf and unixTimestampOf functions take a timeuuid argument and
>   extract the embedded timestamp. However, while the dateof function
>   return it with the timestamp type (that most client, including cqlsh,
>   interpret as a date), the unixTimestampOf function returns it as a
>   bigint raw value.